# How can i change the value of a text field in sencha touch?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, barcode-scanner

I am scanning the barcode using barcode scanner plugins in phonegap. After getting the value, i want to show this in text field. Below is my text field code:

```
{
     xtype : 'textfield',
      id : 'barcodetextfield',
     width : 300,
     margin : '0 0 0 10',
     labelWidth : '40%',
     label : 'Enter Barcode'                                             
}
```

And in the controller, i am trying to set the barcode value in the text field.

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
    this.getBarcodebox.setValue(""+result.text);
 }, function(error) {
     alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
 });
```

And i put the ref in the controller like below:

```
barcodebox : '#barcodetextfield',
```

Here is my whole controller code:::

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.MyController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
config : {
    refs : {
        TitlePanel : 'login',
        dashboardpanel : 'dashboard',
        ConsumerSignup : 'consumersignup',
        AddtoWishlog : 'addwishlog',
        wishlogsummary : 'wishlogsummarylist',
        FeedbackSummary : 'feedbacksummarylist',
        ConsumerSignin : 'Consumersignin',
        barcodebox : '#barcodetextfield',
        labelid : 'title'
    },
    views : [ 'TitlePanel', 'dashboardpanel', 'ConsumerSignup',
            'AddtoWishlog', 'wishlogsummary', 'FeedbackSummary',
            'ConsumerSignin' ],

    control : {
        "#LoginBtn" : {
            tap : 'onLoginButtonTap'
        },

        "#wishloghomebutton" : {
            tap : 'onWishlogHomeButtonTap'
        },

        "#feedbacksummaryhomebutton" : {
            tap : 'onFeedbackHomeButtonTap'
        },

        "#wishlogbtn" : {
            tap : 'onWishlogButtonTap'
        },

        "#Feedbackbtn" : {
            tap : 'onFeedbackButtonTap'
        },

        "#signup" : {
            tap : 'onSignupButtonTap'
        },

        "#capturebtn" : {
            tap : 'onCaptureButtonTap'
        },

        "#consumersignuphomebutton" : {
            tap : 'onConsumerSignupHomeButtonTap'
        },

        "#selectphoto" : {
            tap : 'onSelectPhotoButtonTap'
        },

        "#scanbutton" : {
            tap : 'onScanButtonTap'
        }

    }
},

slideLeftTransition : {
    type : 'slide',
    direction : 'left'
},
slideRightTransition : {
    type : 'slide',
    direction : 'right'
},

onLoginButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getDashboardpanel(),
            this.slideLeftTransition);
    // this.getLabelid.setHtml('Dashboard');
},

onWishlogButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getWishlogsummary(),
            this.slideLeftTransition);
},

onFeedbackButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getFeedbackSummary(),
            this.slideLeftTransition);
},

onSignupButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getConsumerSignup(),
            this.slideLeftTransition);
},

onWishlogHomeButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getDashboardpanel(),
            this.slideRightTransition);
},

onFeedbackHomeButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getDashboardpanel(),
            this.slideRightTransition);
},

onConsumerSignupHomeButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {

    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(this.getDashboardpanel(),
            this.slideRightTransition);
},

onCaptureButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 100,
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // console.log(imageURI);
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('capturedimage');
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
            quality : 100,
            destinationType : destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType : source
        });
    }
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('It is failed: ' + message);
    }

},

onSelectPhotoButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
        quality : 50,
        destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        // console.log(imageURI);
        var largeImage = document.getElementById('capturedimage');
        largeImage.style.display = 'block';
        largeImage.src = imageURI;
    }

    function getPhoto(source) {
        // Retrieve image file location from specified source
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
            quality : 100,
            destinationType : destinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType : source
        });
    }
    function onFail(message) {
        alert('It is failed: ' + message);
    }
},

onScanButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
        this.getBarcodebox().setValue(""+result.text);
```

//          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
//          "Result: " + result.text); 
        }, function(error) {
            alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        });
    }
   });

When i am showing the value in dialog box, it is showing properly. But not able to set in textbox. How i can set the barcode?? Please help.

Comment: the below error i am getting:  Cannot call method 'setValue' of undefined

Answer (score 2):

Should:

```
    this.getBarcodebox.setValue(""+result.text);
```

Not be a method call?

```
    this.getBarcodebox().setValue(""+result.text);
```

This is of course, assuming you have added `barcodebox` as a `ref` in your controller:

```
    refs: {
        barcodebox: '#barcodtext'
    }
```

Note the typo in the `id: #barcodtext` (missing 'e') and make sure that this is equal to the value specified with the `ref` selector.

-- Edit

It look likes that `this` is out of scope in your callback and thus does not refer to your controller. You could try something as following:

```
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
    var controller = Ext.app.Application.getController('MyController');
    controller.getBarcodebox.setValue(""+result.text);
}, function(error) {
    alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
});
```

Comment: I edited the code..you can check..but still getiing error saying:    Error in success callback: BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Cannot call method 'setValue' of undefined

Comment: In your edited code I still do not see the brackets behind getBarcodebox **()** ? Did you add those?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer your code should look like `this.getBarcodebox().setValue(""+result.text);` so with the `()` since it is a method call, not a field.

Comment: Error in success callback: BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'getBarcodebox'                                     this i am getting after adding the braces..

Comment: Could you update your post with the complete controllers code? Maybe we are missing something crucial here.

Comment: But it is giving the error:                                              Error in success callback: BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Object function (){return this.constructor.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'getController'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14449/discussion-between-bjorn-and-arindam-mukherjee)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `barcodebox : '#barcodetextfield',` in `refs` try with `getCmp()`

```
var bc = Ext.getCmp('barcodetextfield');
```

after that `bc.setvalue(''+result.text);`

I hope this helps..

Comment: Tried in this way..although it is not showing any error but it is not giving me the barcode in the text box back